# Which one is the Official Ubuntu Channel?

Tags: youtube

I found 2 Ubuntu Channels on YouTube, [celebrateubuntu](http://www.youtube.com/user/celebrateubuntu/videos) and [planetubuntu](http://www.youtube.com/user/planetubuntu).  Both had similar names, but planetubuntu had more videos.  Which one is the Official Ubuntu Channel?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Celebrate Ubuntu](http://www.youtube.com/user/celebrateubuntu/videos) is an Official channel:

> A new official Ubuntu YouTube channel has popped up stuffed with short promotional videos.

[Planet Ubuntu](http://www.youtube.com/user/planetubuntu) is also an Official channel for Ubuntu.

> Planet Ubuntu is a window into the world, work and lives of Ubuntu developers and contributors.

[Ubuntu Contributor Channel](http://www.youtube.com/user/ubuntudevelopers/feed) is also an Official Ubuntu channel.

So, all three are Official.